# Replace elements of numpy array based on first occurrence of a particular value

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

Suppose there's a numpy 2D array as follows:

```py
>>> x = np.array([[4,2,3,1,1], [1,0,3,2,1], [1,4,4,3,4]])
>>> x
array([[4, 2, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 3, 2, 1],
       [1, 4, 4, 3, 4]])
```

My objective is to - find the first occurrence of value 4 in each row, and set the rest of the elements (including that element) in that row to 0. Hence, after this operation, the transformed array should look like:

```py
>>> x_new
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 3, 2, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

What is the pythonic and optimized way of doing this? I tried with a combination of `np.argmax()` and `np.take()` but was unable to achieve the end objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a cumulative sum across the columns (i.e. `axis=1`) and boolean indexing:

```py
n = 4
idx = np.cumsum(x == n, axis=1) > 0
x[idx] = 0
```

or maybe a better way is to do a cumulative (logical) *or*:

```py
idx = np.logical_or.accumulate(x == n, axis=1)
```